# Application Gets Slow After Enable/Disable MDIChldren

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `Browse` form associated with each MDI child in my application for displaying saved records. I want to disable everything when `Browse` form activate except `Browse` form and Enable everything when `Browse` from close so I used this code.
`Browse` Activated Event

```
public static void DisableControls(Form ParentForm, Form ChildForm)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ParentForm.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ParentForm.Controls[i].GetType() != typeof(MdiClient))
                    ParentForm.Controls[i].Enabled = false;
            }
            foreach (Form frm in ParentForm.MdiChildren)
            {
                if (frm != ChildForm)
                    frm.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

`Browse` Closing Event

```
public static void EnableControls(Form ParentForm)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ParentForm.Controls.Count; i++)
                ParentForm.Controls[i].Enabled = true;

            foreach (Form frm in ParentForm.MdiChildren)
                frm.Enabled = true;
        }
```

This works perfect but if any form have many controls it takes too much to Enable or Disable.
I understand the problem, it's taking time to enable/disable each control of the form.
Is there any option to improve my above code ?

Comment: Approximately how much does it take? can you check with a stopwatch maybe?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen approx 2 sec.

Comment: Just a wild attempt :) You can try using the parallel for (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop) maybe? That might bring up some cross thread issues, but I think it's worth to try.

Comment: Setting the Enabled property of a control is very, very fast.  The only thing that's slow about it is that this code forces every control to repaint itself.  That tends to be pretty visible on a UI with too many controls.  "Use less controls" is the kind of advice that's invariably useless, consider hiding some windows instead of disabling them.  Google "windows forms ws_ex_composited" for a possible band-aid.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Do you mean, `Foreach` is the main issue ? But as I said, it gets slow only if Form has many controls. It works perfect with form containing few controls.

Comment: My idea was it waits for each control to finish with the regular foreach or for. That's why I suggest to use the parallel for or foreach. So that they won't wait for each other.

Comment: @HansPassant, in that case isn't it possible to remove (halt somehow) the paint event at the beginning of this function of OP, and repaint all after the enabling is done?

Comment: Why loop over all the controls on a form when you can just disable the form itself?

Comment: Alternatively, use ShowDialog to show your Browse form that way all controls on other forms are effectively blocked.

Comment: @HandbagCrab I want to use `Browse` as a MDIChild

Comment: Then just disable the forms themselves instead of all the controls on the forms. It'll have the same effect but will be a lot quicker.